# El nombre '' no existe en el contexto actual. C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buenas tardes
Tengo una funcionalidad para generar un archivo Excel a partir de una plantilla. Haciendo clic en un botón se ejecuta el código y ver los datos contenidos en las variables "listaTema", "listaProyectos" dice:  El nombre '....' no existe en el contexto actual.
No encuentro la razón del porque esas variables quedan sin contexto.

```
    protected void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FundacionBL fundacionBL = new FundacionBL();
        FundacionBE fundacionBE = new FundacionBE();
        fundacionBE = fundacionBL.Consultar(Convert.ToInt32(ddlFundacion.SelectedValue));

        hdServerPath.Value = Server.MapPath("../Archivos/Excel/");
        string sPlantillaOrigen = hdServerPath.Value + "PLANTILLA_PROYECTOS_SIF.xlsm";
        hdArchivoDestino.Value = fundacionBE.Sigla + "-ProyectosInvestigaciones.xlsm";

        // Generar archivo Excel de la fundación seleccionada.
        int idFundacion = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFundacion.SelectedValue.ToString());
        GenerarArchivoExcel(idFundacion, sPlantillaOrigen, hdServerPath.Value.ToString() + hdArchivoDestino.Value.ToString());

        // Mostrar mensaje final.
        this.Master.MostrarMensaje(Comunes.Constantes.MSJ_EXCEL_CREAR, SIFMasterPage.TipoMensaje.Informacion);
        btnDescargar.Visible = true;
    }

    private void GenerarArchivoExcel(int idFundacion, string sPlantillaOrigen, string sArchivoDestino)
    {
        // Cargar los temas para filtro de temas
        DominioBL dominioBL = new DominioBL();
        List<DominioBE> listaTema = new List<DominioBE>();
        listaTema = dominioBL.ConsultarTemas();

        // Cargar los proyectos de la fundación
        ProyectoExcelBL proyectoExcelBL = new ProyectoExcelBL();
        List<ProyectoExcelBE> listaProyectos = new List<ProyectoExcelBE>();
        listaProyectos = proyectoExcelBL.Consultar(idFundacion);

        // Si existe el archivo de salida se elimina primero.
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(sArchivoDestino)) System.IO.File.Delete(sArchivoDestino);

        System.Reflection.Missing Default = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        OfficeExcel.Application ExcelAPP = new OfficeExcel.Application();
        OfficeExcel._Workbook LibroWB = ExcelAPP.Workbooks.Open(sPlantillaOrigen, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default);

        // Llenar la hoja oculta de Temas para el combo de Temas
        OfficeExcel._Worksheet HojaTema = (OfficeExcel._Worksheet)LibroWB.Worksheets["SeleccionarTema"];

        // TODO. Ciclo de la lista de Temas
        HojaTema.Cells[3, 1] = "OK";

        // Guardar Como el libro Excel destino.
        LibroWB.SaveAs(sArchivoDestino, Default, Default, Default, false, Default, OfficeExcel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Default, Default, Default, Default, Default);
        LibroWB.Close(Default, Default, Default);
        ExcelAPP.Quit();
    }
```

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindar

Comment: Las imagenes no se pueden ver, por favor agrega el codigo en lugar de imagenes.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: acalara cuales son las variables sin contexto, y por favor pon el error completo que te tira visual studio.. probaste recompilar?

Comment: Las variables que visual studio dice que no existen en el contexto actual son "listaTema" y "listaProyectos" que pertenecen a  la rutina "GenerarArchivoExcel". El proyecto compila bien. Cuando se ejecuta y se pone un breakpoint para ver el contenido de esas dos variables, en la ventana inmediato no contiene ningún dato. ?listaTema
El nombre 'listaTema' no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: intellisense tampoco las ve?? no las tendras definidas a otro nivel tambien?

Comment: Definidas a otro nivel?... No, están justo en la rutina 'GenerarArchivoExcel' definidas localmente. List<DominioBE> listaTema = new List<DominioBE>();

Comment: si si.. las veo.. pero digo, pq si esta protestando.. por algo es.. obviamente es imposible reproducir tu problema...

Comment: Acabo de renombrarlas por 'lstTema' y 'lstProyectos'. No existe ningún otro objeto en toda la solución que tengan esos nombres y sin embargo visual studio sigue indicando que no existen en el contexto actual.

Comment: Por si necesitan una posible solución. En mi caso, VS estaba en modo 'Release' al ejecutar la aplicación. Se colocó en modo 'Debug' y funcionó. No se que tiene que ver ello, pues siempre antes se había ejecutado en modo 'Release' y todas las variables de tipo List<> funcionaban correctamente.